# jQuery Ajax call sometimes fires error after success, if navigating away

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have a jQuery ajax POST call that is all working; the data is saved, server executes OK, returns 200 status, and the success event fires ... but then the error event sometimes* fires as well!

In the success event, I navigate to a different page.

If I don't navigate away, the error event does not fire.

```
$.ajax({
    url: serviceUrl + '/SetOptionLineStructure',
    data: JSON.stringify({ "content": RetrieveLineStructure() }),
    success: function (data) {
        $('#resultText').html('Succeeded');

        if (data.d.Succeeded) {
            window.location.href = "Anotherpage.aspx";
            }
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
        $('#resultText').html('An error occurred saving: ' + textStatus + ' ' + xhr.status);
    },
    complete: function (xhr, textStatus) {
    }
});
```

So I see 'Succeeded' followed quickly by 'An error occurred saving: error 0'.
My thought is that somehow navigating to another page at this point prevents the ajax request from closing properly.

This is somewhat cosmetic, because the functionality is actually fine, but we show an error message briefly. I could suppress this with a hack but that seems ugly.

- Sometimes: this only happens on some ajax calls. I haven't figured out the pattern to which ones cause the issue and which don't.

Cheers

Comment: Well I've added my global variable hack to suppress the error message. Everything looks lovely on the surface :)